# Free drawing inside a object using fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I loaded multiple objects from svg by following code:

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('drawing');
 fabric.loadSVGFromURL('images/circle.svg', function(objects) {
 canvas.add.apply(canvas, objects);
 canvas.forEachObject(function(o){ o.hasBorders = o.hasControls = false; 
         });
 canvas.renderAll();
 });
```

Now I want to free draw only inside one object(like the image below).How can I achieve that using fabric.js?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **mask the canvas** (using `canvas.clipTo`) and make it match your SVG form. If it is a circle as in your example image it would be simple.

See the following example:

```js
// define a drawing canvas
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(
  'drawing', 
  { isDrawingMode: true }
);
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'red'

// create a circle (here you could load your svg circle instead)
const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  top: 25, 
  left: 25, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: 'transparent', 
  stroke: 'black' 
});

// create the clipping mask using the circle coordinates
canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
  ctx.arc(
    circle.top + circle.radius, 
    circle.left + circle.radius, 
    circle.radius + 1, // +1px for the circle stroke
    circle.radius + 1, 
    Math.PI*2, 
    true
  )
}

// add the circle to the canvas
canvas.add(circle);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.5/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="drawing" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks! but if I want to clip with a svg path instead of a circle, what should I use instead of arc?

Comment: You have the entire [canvas api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) to draw, it's not limited to arc. I did use circle since it matched your question requirements and example.